# Updating Azure Container Registry Public Access IP with Python

Tags: python, azure

I've tried looking online but could not find an answer as the documentation (and the API) for Azure Python SDK is just horrible.

I have a Container Registery on Azure with a list of allowed IPs for public access. I'd like to modify that list by adding a new IP using Python.

I'm not sure the API supports it or how to achieve this using `ContainerRegistryManagementClient`.

Comment: @StanleyGong I replied to your comment below. Thank you for the follow-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't agree more that documentation (and the API) for Azure Python SDK is just horrible :)

If you want to add a list of allowed IPs for public access to your Container Registery on Azure, just try the code below using REST API:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
import requests

TENANT_ID= ""
CLIENT_ID = ""
CLIENT_SECRET = ""

SUBSCRIPTION_ID = ""
GROUP_NAME = ""
REGISTRIES = ""


#your public ip list here
ALLOWED_IPS = [{
                    "value": "167.220.255.1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "167.220.255.2"
                }
            ]


clientCred = ClientSecretCredential(TENANT_ID,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET)

authResp = clientCred.get_token("https://management.azure.com/.default")

requestURL = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/'+SUBSCRIPTION_ID+'/resourceGroups/'+GROUP_NAME+'/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/'+REGISTRIES+'?api-version=2020-11-01-preview'
requestBody = {
    "properties": {
        "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
        "networkRuleSet": {
            "defaultAction": "Deny",
            "virtualNetworkRules": [],
            "ipRules": ALLOWED_IPS
        },
        "networkRuleBypassOptions": "AzureServices"
    }
}

r = requests.patch(url=requestURL,json=requestBody,headers={"Authorization":"Bearer "+ authResp.token})

print(r.text)
```

Result:

[image]

Before you run this, pls make sure that your client app has been granted the required permissions([Azure subscription roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles), such as contributor).

Comment: That's a neat trick! I'm able to perform this action over the web UI, however, when using the code, I get: `{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'CLIENT_ID' with object id 'CLIENT_ID' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/write' over scope '/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/CONTAINER_REGISTRY_NAME' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}`. It does not make sense to me, because the web UI works.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams It is due to your AD application has no permission to do this action. You should assign an associated role to it. i,e contributor role, details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-steps

Comment: @StanlleyGong Thanks, I'll look into it. Is there a way to add a new IP to the allowed IP instead of patching the whole list?

Comment: @GilbertWilliams,welcome, yes, if you just want to add one new IP, just try :ALLOWED_IPS = [{
                    "value": "<new IP>"
                }
            ]

Comment: @GilbertWilliams How's going? Has your issue got resolved? If my post is helpful, pls accept it as an answer, thx!

Comment: I ended up invoking the Azure CLI from within Python as the API is not good.